# Graphics development on ARM

Tags: graphics, operating-system, arm, simulator, qemu

I am planning to make a small OS and run a Tetris clone on it using an ARM Cortex-M3. Unfortunately, I am not able to buy any development boards as of now, so I will have to use simulators.

I have actually looked into QEMU which has LM3S6965EVB support, which contains an ARM Cortex-M3 processor. But apparently newer revisions of the board are not compatible with the model in QEMU as none of the examples I have downloaded from TI seem to work. Even the OLED display is different.

Another problem is to do graphics development as the OLED display for LM3S6965EVB has a really low resolution. I was able to get it up to 640x480 by editing the QEMU source but as I could not get any examples to work, so I don't know if it works either. Using the debug parameters for SSD0323, all I can see is that it accepts some of the data that is sent to initialize the device, then hangs...

I have considered choosing another board in QEMU but that would mean redoing many things from scratch when I get my hands on a real device, as the other ones are too powerful for something as simple as this.

What should I do? Are there any other simulators out there that can help me accomplish what I am trying to do? I want to develop a small OS and some small games.

Thanks in advance. I have been searching for a solution for days and I am really stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much you have to redo, in part, has to do with your software/system engineering, you can abstract where needed and only have to re-write the abstraction layer not the entire package.  Actually you can do much of your software design/testing on your host system and never cross compile, only later cross compile to a simulator or real hardware.

For example, I assume you would construct the next video screen somewhere in ram then depending on the hardware change some bits in a register and page flip or have to do a copy from this frame buffer to the video/lcd in whatever form it wants.  Using thumbulator you could build your screen in ram somewhere (in the simulated memory space) then add to the simulator when the simulation writes to such and such register take these bytes from ram and display them on the host computer (running the simulation) basically simulate some hardware.  use sdl or basic X calls or whatever you prefer.  I normally take snapshots to .bmp files (very easy to write) then look at them later.

Later, on hardware your abstracted update_screen() function would have hardware specific code to display that screen.

thumbulator only runs thumb instructions not ARM and not Thumb2, thumb being the common denominator between the arm processors (ARMv4T and newer except for cortex-m) and those that support thumb2 extensions (cortex-m).  other than startup code the compiling and programming experience is the same across the arm family.  the code (other than startup code and of course hardware specific accesses) will run across the arm family as well as the simulator.  If you go to a cortex-m then adding an architecture specification to the command line will change the build from thumb only to thumb+thumb2 instructions giving you some performance boost.  if you surf around my other projects on github you will find this idea reapeated over and over again, I have many simple cortex-m examples where I use gcc and llvm and build the same .C code with thumb instructions and thumb+thumb2.

Another completely different answer is get a GBA (Nintendo Game Boy Advance).  You can get a GBA SP (has a backlit display, makes the whole experience better) for about $30 or so on ebay.  You can buy flash cartridges that take sd cards for about the same amount.  It has an ARM7TDMI, it runs thumb code much faster than ARM code, giving you that thumb experience in preparation for other/newer cores like the cortex-m.  For another $30 you can get a game link cable, chop it up, attach a rs232 level shifter (I can talk you through all of this), and make a gba serial cable.  My preferred setup is to have a flash cartridge that I have pre-programmed with a serial bootloader, I download the program over serial into ram then run from ram.  This avoids having to yank the flash cartridge and/or sd card every time you re-compile the program.  doable, and a cheaper solution but gets tiring fast.

If you have a Nintendo DS for $12 to $15 you can get an sd based flash cartridge that you can likewise use for development.  I recommend learning the gba first, which you can do on the NDS if you buy a gba side memory cartridge (need a ds lite not an ndsi nor 3d) supported by the software on the cartridge. (the ez flash 3 in 1 gba size for example is a good one, as well as memory you can flash that one with the nds and carry it over to the gba (this is how I put my serial bootloader on it)).  these loaders will let you put your .gba file on the nds cartridge sd card then load it into the gba cartridge and it switches the nds into gba mode and runs as a gba.

there are lots of other solutions, sparkfun.com likely has a number of arm based boards that can drive lcds and/or come with lcds.  You can go to earthlcd and get one of the serial based lcd panels that make for rapid development, later of course a cheaper solution is desired.  Along the same lines you could instead simulate an earthlcd like thing using your host computer have the embedded microcontroller send screen updates over serial to the host and the host displays the graphics.  Later replace that screen update with something else.

This latter solution, for about $20 you can get a stm32f4 discovery board, has a cortex-m4, runs up to 168MHz, has a number of serial ports of which at least two have pins not being used by something else you could easily have one port for debug messages and the other for this virtual serial screen.  In the stm32f4 directory in my stm32vld repo on github I have a number of getting started examples for using that board (as well as the stm32vld which is a few bucks cheaper but not as powerful as this stm32f4).  Likewise your host application can take keystrokes and turn them into user control/game control commands back into the game software on the microcontroller.

There is of course the beagleboard or hawkboard or raspberri pi when it comes out, or open-rd (I dont like the plug computer but do like the open rd) which have video processing and video output direct to a monitor and/or tv using composite or whatever.  About $150 to $200 and it just works run with it.  You definitely dont need to run linux on these platforms, you can make your own os or whatever you like and run that, very simple.

There are more solutions than you probably have time and/or money to pursue you need to find one that fits within your comfort or happyness zone for how you like to do development and try that path.

Comment: Thanks very much. It was really helpful. I will think about what you have said.

Comment: Oh, also look at embeddedarm.com, might have something that connects directly to an lcd, ARM based, etc.

Comment: Well, these are too powerful for my goals. Actually I was thinking of something with an VGA output and SD card for games so I would be able to connect it to a monitor or a projector; making it a homebrewn gaming console in the end.

I have run across another problem though, apparently the resolution I want (640x480) is too big for many chips as they have only 64 KB SRAM; so I need to find a chip with external memory support too. As games will reside in SD card, I think that trying to read graphics from it would be slow... Thanks anyway, I think I will use Thumbulator with SDL.